# How to terminate only certain pods based on wheather or not they have finnished a certain task in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm having trouble with finding a solution that allows to terminate only certain pods in a deployment.

The application running inside the pods does some processing which can a take lot of time to be finished.

Let's say I have 10 tasks that are stored in a database and I issue a command to scale the deployment to 10 pods.

Let's say that after some time 3 of the pods have finished their tasks and are no longer required.
How can i scale down the deployment from 10 to 7 while terminate only the pods that have finished the tasks and not the pods that are still processing those tasks?

I don't know if more details are needed but i will happily edit the question if there are more details needed to give an answer for this kind of problem.

Comment: That is an interesting scenario. Given the nature of your deployment, can they run as Jobs in alternative to Deployments? That would allow simple pod completion once the task finishes.

Comment: yes, sounds like you want to use a Job and not Deployment.

Comment: Yeah it looks like jobs are more suitable for these types of scenarios.
Guess i gotta change the code to accommodate job scheduling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case Kubernetes Job might be better suited for this kind of task.